# Изменить текст кнопки в html в input type="file (Bootstrap4)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap4, html-form

Есть форма. Принимает файлы. Используется bootstap4. По стандарту в стилях написано Choose file справа от кнопки надпись No file chosen. Я не могу поменять, как поменять данный текст. И стили тыкал через Css и т.д,

Вот код HTML

```
<div class="form-group rez">
        <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Прикрепите Ваше резюме</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control-file custom-file-control" id="fileRezym" name="fileRezym">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Изменить текст этой кнопки невозможно. Можно только скрыть само поле `<input>` и вызывать диалог открытия файла кликом по полю через JS.

Либо, если надо иметь поле для дропа файлов, сделать `<input>` просто невидимым.

Либо есть библиотека [FilePond](https://pqina.nl/filepond/), с Bootstrap вроде неплохо работает.